# XSLT special condition for first row

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an xml file with xslt.

I need to have the values grouped in a div tag.
First row the div tag should have a special class `<div class="firstrow">`
All other rows should have `<div class="tabpanel">`.

How can I assign the class="firstrow" for first row and all other rows with class="tabpanel"?

source xml

```
<row>
   <column1>ABC</<column1>
   <column2>ABC</<column2>
</row>
<row>
   <column1>123</<column1>
   <column2>123</<column2>
</row>
<row>
   <column1>234</<column1>
   <column2>234</<column2>
</row>
```

Output I want

```
<div class="firstrow">
   ABC
   ABC
</div>
<div class="tabpanel">
   123
   123
</div>
<div class="tabpanel">
   234
   234
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="row[1]">
     <div class="firstrow"><xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="row">
     <div class="tabpanel"><xsl:value-of select="."/></div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document** (the provided one, made well-formed!):

```
<t>
    <row>
        <column1>ABC</column1>
        <column2>ABC</column2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column1>123</column1>
        <column2>123</column2>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column1>234</column1>
        <column2>234</column2>
    </row>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<div class="firstrow">
        ABC
        ABC
    </div>

<div class="tabpanel">
        123
        123
    </div>

<div class="tabpanel">
        234
        234
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank You. Is there any other way than using the template? In this case I need to repeat the div tag twice (my div tag is not just listing two rows but it has lot of functionalities)

Comment: If the only difference between the two cases should be in the class attribute, and the rest of the template is complex enough that you don't want to duplicate, make the template match on `row` and define a variable $class whose value is <xsl:choose> <xsl:when test="not(preceding-sibling::row)">firstrow</xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise>tabpanel</xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose>, and write the div start-tag as `<div class="{$class}">...

Comment: @Tippu, So, in order not to repeat a `div`, you have accepted an answer that is twice as long, much more complicated and error prone than this one -- Congratulations! As for "other functionalities" that you haven't shown in the question, how do expect us to guess about "them"? I have shown you the best XSLT style: no `xsl:for-each`, no `xsl:if` no `xsl:call-template`, no named templates -- you are free to ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

Firt of all , there should be a root element in your source xml, so I changed it as follows:

**Source Xml**

```
<rows>
  <row>
    <column1>
      ABC
    </column1>
    <column2>
      ABC
    </column2>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column1>
      123
    </column1>
    <column2>
      123
    </column2>
  </row>
  <row>
    <column1>
      234
    </column1>
    <column2>
      234
    </column2>
  </row>
</rows>
```

**Required Xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="rows">
      <xsl:for-each select="row">
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
          <div class="firstrow">
            <xsl:call-template name="PrintColumnValues"></xsl:call-template>
          </div>
        </xsl:if>
        <div class="tabpanel">
          <xsl:call-template name="PrintColumnValues"></xsl:call-template>
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="PrintColumnValues">
    <xsl:value-of select="column1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="column2"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After transforming source xml using this xslt you will get desired html output.

NOTE: As a help here I am adding some code that can be used for xslt transformation.

```
public static string TransformContentXmlwithXslt(XmlDocument xmlDocument, string xsltFileName)
    {
        //Load the XML data document
        MemoryStream contentStream = new MemoryStream();
        xmlDocument.Save(contentStream);
        contentStream.Position = 0;
        XPathDocument mergedXPathDocument = new XPathDocument(contentStream);
        XsltSettings xsltJsSetting = new XsltSettings();
        xsltJsSetting.EnableScript = true;

        //Load the XSLT file
        string xsltFilePath = xsltFileName;
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load(xsltFilePath, xsltJsSetting, new XmlUrlResolver());

        //Do the transformation
        MemoryStream transformedContentMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(transformedContentMemoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(transformedContentMemoryStream);
        xslt.Transform(mergedXPathDocument, writer);
        transformedContentMemoryStream.Position = 0;
        string transformedHtml = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        //// Close the connections
        streamReader.Close();
        transformedContentMemoryStream.Close();

        return transformedHtml;
    }
```

*Here, `xsltFileName` should contain full file path.*

You can get the transformed output by calling this method.

Comment: Yikes. No offense, but although your answer works, it's confusing, inefficient, and breaks several key XSLT design principles.

Comment: @ABach willing to know the XSLT design principles thar broke by above answer, (for knowledge gaining purposes)

Comment: Please look at @DimitreNovatchev's answer below for a more concise, reusable solution (no `<xsl:if>` where not needed, no `<xsl:for-each>`, no named templates, etc.). Again, absolutely no disrespect to you - your answer does, indeed, work; his, however, is a great model to follow. Thanks for being willing to expand your understanding of XSLT.