# Exporting specifyied records from portal

Tags: filemaker

Hi does anyone know if it's possible to export specified records from a portal in XML? Currently when I filter the portal it exports all records in the relationship and ignores the portal filter. Is it possible to specify which records to export from a portal without modifying the relationship?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to specify which records to export from a portal
>   without modifying the relationship?

Not really. Well, at least in theory, you *could* go to the related records and perform a Constrain Found Set there to replicate the filter's action. But then you would have to implement the same logic twice, violating [the DRY principle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

If you need the filtered results at the data layer (e.g. for export), then it's time to filter the relationship. Portal filtering is meant for display purposes only.

**Note**: this is assuming that you actually need this filtering for display purposes, too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the problem with filtering the relationships is the records I'm pulling in are from an SQL database and I cannot modify these records. I'm using an additional related filemaker table to allow the user to select which records they wish to export from the portal. Do you have any suggestions about how I could filter the relationship?

Comment: 1. Why would you need to modify the source records in order to filter them? --  2. Is a portal even required here? Perhaps you could just perform a find in the source table itself?

Comment: I have an orders table and an operations table I wish to export information about the order then the selected operations. If I did it straight from the source table I wouldn't have access to order information unless I pulled it through with each operation. The reason I said about modifying the source table was becuase currently the users selection is stored in a filemaker table not sql.

Comment: "*If I did it straight from the source table I wouldn't have access to order information unless I pulled it through with each operation.*" That's certainly an option worth considering - esp. if you're exporting as XML and can shape your result using XSLT. The only valid reason not to do this is if you need to include orders that do not have any operations.  ----  "*The reason I said about modifying the source table was becuase currently the users selection is stored in a filemaker table not sql.*"  I am afraid I'm still not with you on that.

Comment: Ok, do you know how I could go about only retreiving the order information once then retreiving each operation?

Comment: You would simply include fields from the orders table in the export. Then use XSLT to group the exported rows by the (included) OrderID field. I suggest you post a new question about that, and include a small example of the raw XML export + the expected output.

Comment: Its ok got it, thanks for your help. Found the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840585/xslt-special-condition-for-first-row